# Como carregar imagem a partir do javascript usando base64?

Tags: javascript, html5, lightbox

Boa noite, estou usando desse plugin: http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#single-image

Aqui está JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30015/

Segue o código:

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Abrir imagem</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$("button[class='btn btn-primary']").click(function(e) {
var imagem = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAM ... etc'
event.preventDefault();
  $(this).ekkoLightbox({
  //Como carregar imagem a partir daqui
  });
});
```

É possível carregar imagem a partir javascript ?

Comment: Basta criar o elemento img e definir o atributo src como sendo o texto base 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com jQuery, você pode alterar o *source* da imagem usando [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) ou [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
var imagem = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/...';
$("algum_seletor").attr('src', imagem);
```

Com isso é possível aplicar alguma lógica no *ekkoLightbox*.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/30020/